# How to use vowpal wabbit for online prediction (streaming mode)

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am trying to use Vowpal Wabbit for one multi class classification task with 154 different class labels as follows:

1. Trained VW model with large amount of data.
2. Tested the model with one dedicated test set.

In this scenario I was able to hit >80% result, which is good. But the problem which currently I am working on is:

I have to replicate the real time prediction scenario. In this case I have to pass one data point (i.e text line) at a time so that model can predict the value and output.

I have tried out all the options which I knew but failed. Can any of you let me know how to create a real time scenario by passing one data point along with VW command but not as a file.

Comment: The title is misleading. The question is not about passing the input data as command line parameter (e.g. `vw --example "| featureA featureB"` which is not possible in VW). It is about using VW for online prediction (streaming mode).

Comment: Thanks Martin, you're right. I suggested an edit to the title. Hope it is approved.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `vw` as a daemon:

```
vw --daemon --port 54321 --quiet -i model_file -t --num_children 1
```

Now `vw` loads the model and listens on port 54321 (on localhost).  Every time you send a line (ending with a newline, ASCII 10) to `localhost:54321` you'll get a prediction back on the same socket, for example:

```
echo " | your features here..." | netcat localhost 54321
```

This is just an example, normally you would write a program that will write and then read from the socket in a loop instead of calling `netcat`.

You can also call `vw` in regular input/output and prediction mode:

```
vw --quiet -i model_file -t -p /dev/stdout
```

And write to it (via `stdin`) and read from it (via `stdout`).  The key is that you'll get one line of output for each line of input you send, in the same order.  You can also send `N` lines at a time, and then read back `N` responses. The order relative order of requests vs responses is guaranteed to be preserved.